# imbalanced learning: precision vs recall trade-off

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, precision-recall

Working on a multi-class problem (five classes) for which the dataset is highly imbalanced (two classes with less than 2% samples).

Which metric between `precision` and `recall` should I pay more attention to?

```
print(classification_report)
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     Class 0       0.24      0.01      0.02     12826
     Class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00      1380
     Class 2       0.00      0.00      0.00      6543
     Class 3       0.51      0.98      0.67     22856
     Class 4       0.00      0.00      0.00      1561

    accuracy                           0.50     45166
   macro avg       0.15      0.20      0.14     45166
weighted avg       0.33      0.50      0.34     45166
```

Comment: Neither. Both of those are for binary problems.

Comment: I understand, but one can compute these metrics in a multi-classification problem as in one-against-others, for example, the  the `classification_report` from my current work in the question edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one. You should aim for well-calibrated and sharp probabilistic predictions of class membership. ([Note that "unbalanced classes" cease to be a problem in this setting.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)) Once you have these predictions, you can choose actions to apply to each instance based on your predictions and the costs of wrong actions. This may involve a threshold, but note that the threshold pertains to the *decision* aspect, not the *statistical* part of the exercise, and requires a notion of cost or utility.

[More here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352) And [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352).